# 'Asset' object has no attribute 'startswith' when using avatar_url with create_webhook

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a command that creates a webhook, creating the webhook and name works find but when i add `avatar` and set it to the avatar url of the person mentioned I get error: `'Asset' object has no attribute 'startswith'` I think i may have to use `with open` or anything like that to open the image from my pc which i dodn't want, i want it to be the image of the mentioned person not an image file from my Pc, anyway to do this?

```
@bot.command()
async def whook(ctx,user:discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.create_webhook(name="Mr. W.Hook",avatar=user.avatar_url)
    print("Created")
```

Comment: Avatar needs to be a [bytes-like object](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_webhook). You could invoke user.avatar_url ,download it locally and then set it.

Comment: Thought of that but just didn't know how to do it, how would I download the user's avatar?